# Не понимаю на каком этапе у меня не передаются данные с Vue в Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

У меня есть страница с задачами `Tasks` и кнопка, которая вызывает фильтр `TasksFilter`. Туда я указываю с какой даты мне нужно вывести задачи, при сохранении `submit` заново открывается route данной страницы, но при этом передается дата. Также есть кнопка сброса `reset`. Вот их код

```
submit() {
      this.$inertia.get(route('dashboard.tasks'), {
        start_date: this.start_date,
      });
    },
reset() {
      this.$inertia.get(route('dashboard.tasks'), {
        start_date: '',
      });
    }
```

Дальше у меня идет контроллер:

```
public function tasks(Request $request)
{
    return $this->service->tasks($request);
}
```

и сервис, где логика фильтра:

```
public function tasks(Request $request)
{
    $startDate = $request->start_date;
    $tasks = Task::with('work.reserve')->whereHas('work', function ($query) use ($startDate) {
          if ($startDate){ $query->where('start_date', '>=', $startDate);}})->get();
    return Inertia::render('Tasks', ['tasks' => $tasks, 'started_at' => $request->started_at]);
}
```

Написано все на vuejs 3 и laravel 10

UPD: Вопрос в том, что как можно проверить, где пропадает значение?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Какие ошибки и на чьей стороне?

Comment: @lezhni значения не попадают в контроллер и соответственно в сервис при проверке 'dd($request->start_Date)' выдает 'null'

Comment: start_date и start_Date это разные параметры (они регистрочувствительные), может ошибка в этой опечатке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том что у меня данные берутся из формы и я забыл это указать

```
submit() {
  this.$inertia.get(route('dashboard.tasks'), {
    start_date: this.form.start_date,
  });
```